# Spring RestController return false for boolean by default

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have the below field defined in my bean and I explicitly set the value for this boolean value to null. However when I return this as part of my JSON response using my rest controller , it return the value as false instead of null. Is there a way to return the value as null?

```
public Boolean isActive;
```

Comment: Do you have any jackson annotation on the POJO class, which contains the isActive attribute?

Comment: No , I haven't defined any jackson annotation in this specific POJO

Comment: Quite interesting, just a moment ago i tried it and got null value as expected. Do you have any setter/getter methods for this attribute and how are they looking? The problem may be the is- prefix on the attribute.

Comment: Thanks ! I have another attribute  "public Boolean primaryIndicator" for which I am facing the same issue. Yes , they have getters and setters.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are using?

Comment: @PunterVicky how did you name the getters/setters and what version of Jackson are you using?